# php SELECT list of fonts in their respective font face

Tags: php, css, select, fonts

I've seen similar questions but no real answers.
I have successfully created a dropdown select list of fonts in a local directory that allows the user to select a font that is then used to generate a label.
I am trying to get the font list to display each font option as the font itself.
I have successfully had an option list with different font styles when explicitly stating the font family for each option. I have; however, been unable to make it work dynamically.

Please play with the following code and let me know if there is any syntax problems and also if you have a better idea.... I am open to all suggestions and Thanks in advance.

```
  <?php
// open the current directory

$dhandle = opendir('/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/');
// define an array to hold the files
$files = array();

if ($dhandle) {
   // loop through all of the files
   while (false !== ($fname = readdir($dhandle))) {
      // if the file is not this file, and does not start with a '.' or '..',
      // then store it for later display
      if (($fname != '.') && ($fname != '..') &&
          ($fname != basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']))) {
          // store the filename
          $files[] = (is_dir( "./$fname" )) ? "(Dir) {$fname}" : $fname;
      }
   }
   // close the directory
  closedir($dhandle);
}
echo "<select name=\"fonts\">\n";
echo "<option name=\"tops\" value=\"\">Select Font</option>\n";
// Now loop through the files, echoing out a new select option for each one
foreach( $files as $fname )
 {
  echo "<option value=$fname STYLE=\"font-family: {$fname};src: local(\'explode (\'$files\')\');font-size : 14pt;\">$fname</option>\n";
 }
 echo "</select>\n";
?>
```

Comment: Fonts must be resident on the user's system in order for them to render. You could provide them via CSS @font declarations.

Comment: I tried using "@font-face inline and it made no difference... it didn't break anything.  using @font in the header doesn't seem to be an answer cause it still has to be dynamic. That's why I shared what is a nearly functioning script.  I mean the font list is generated, the user selects a font and that font is successfully applied on the next page with imagefttext.

Comment: You need to add the @font-face declarations to a CSS file and load that somehow. If you do that then you also need to have the fonts available online somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to embeed google fonts from this link:

http://www.google.com/fonts

This is the way to do it:

Let's say you want the font: `Roboto`.

If you click on the second icon located at bottom right of the font item, you will be redirected to a page where you will be provide with this code:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Which is what you have to add to your `<head></head>` section in order to make the font available on your page, and:

```
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
```

Which is what you have to write to apply the font to an element in your **CSS** declaration.

So, what you can do with this approach is

1- select the fonts you would like to make availables for users to chose from (there are tons, you can have fun selecting them)

2- make your dinamic list of fonts storing them in a database or in a **PHP** class

3- display the selection so the user can choose a font:

```
$fonts = array("Roboto", "Oswald", "Indie Flower");

//head section
foreach($fonts as $font)
{
  echo "<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=".str_replace(" ", "+", $font)."' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>\n";
}

//body section
foreach($fonts as $font)
{
  echo "<option value=\"".$font."\" STYLE=\"font-family: ".$font.";\">".$font."</option>\n";
}
```

I think I don't need to explain more. But feel free to ask me any question if you have doubts.

Comment: I appreciate the info, and it is cool. But this is going in an offline appliance and will probably not be on the internet.  I am probably going to do the following:  Move all relevant fonts into a folder in the same directory as the web page, create a css that does @font-face for every font in that directory, then the dynamic stuff should work fine.  I'll keep you updated, but don't stop suggesting stuff ..  I am very grateful.